# Get the relations between dimensions and measure groups

Tags: ado.net, ssas, mdx, xmla

There is the *"Show fields related to:"* feature in Excel:
[image]
I want something like this, but return in the following form:

```
MeasureGroup1: Dimension1, Dimension2, Dimesion3
MeasureGroup2: Dimension2, Dimesion3
...
```

Can't find out how Excel retrieve this data. I need to write a script which will automatically generate the relationship data for a chosen cube. It can be MDX or XMLA. ADO.NET in the last resort (it should be a portable script after all).

Hope you can help.

Comment: really unsure of how to do this - the mdx function EXISTS uses measure group as its 3rd argument - would this function help?

Comment: Not really, It works with sets and querying huge dimensions is heavy. There is also MeasureGroupMeasures('MeasureGroup1').Item(0), however doesn't work with Visible = False measures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following returns a recordset which Excel uses to determine which dimensions are related to which measure groups:

```
select *
from $system.MDSCHEMA_MEASUREGROUP_DIMENSIONS
```

Comment: Exactly what I want! Shame on me: didn't manage to find it before. Thanks, Greg!

Comment: There is possible to use xmla for these things, which even is more native for clients like Excel! I've posted the code as an extra answer.

Answer (score 1):

Plus the xmla solution:

```
<Discover xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis">
    <RequestType>MDSCHEMA_MEASUREGROUP_DIMENSIONS</RequestType>
    <Restrictions />
    <Properties />
</Discover>
```